# How do I make these two buttons one and the rotation if off (presuming I've done it correctly)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have these two buttons below. One is for adding an image in and viewing it with another image over the top of that. The other button checks he resolution of the image. I would like to only have one button that preforms both those functions but can't seem to get it to read the image resolution check function when you upload an image.

The other thing that I can't seem to fix / figure out is when some portrait images are uploaded they're displayed horizontally instead of vertically?

Ive been trying to figure these things out for the last few days before asking for any help but its got to the point where I can't think of anything else that may work.....

(Any help is much appreciated!)

First Button Code:

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <br>
    <img id="blah" src="" alt="Upload Image" />

     <img id="blah2" src="" alt="Upload Image" />

     <img id="grooved" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/elderscrolls/images/e/ec/Ok-icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20120124042116" alt="your image" height="100" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });

    function readURL2(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah2').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL2(this);
    });
```

Css:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    background-color: #555;
}

#blah {
 width:500px; 
  height:500px;
  background-image: url('path/to/image');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#blah2 {
 width:500px; 
  height:500px;
  background-image: url('path/to/image');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}

#grooved {
  position: absolute; left: 280px;
}
```

Second Button :

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="destination.html">
    <input type="file" id="filePicker" />
    <br/>
    <div id="noFileError" style="display:none;">
        <b>Please select a valid image file.</b>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <br/>
    <div id="imageValidationError" style="display:none;">
        <b>The image resolution is too low.</b>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function isSupportedBrowser() {
    return window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Image;
}

function getSelectedFile() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("filePicker");
    var fileIsSelected = fileInput && fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0];
    if (fileIsSelected)
        return fileInput.files[0];
    else
        return false;
}

function isGoodImage(file) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function() {
        // Check if image is bad/invalid
        if (this.width + this.height === 0) {
            this.onerror();
            return;
        }

        // Check the image resolution
        if (this.width >= 1191 && this.height >= 1191) {
            deferred.resolve(true);
        } else {
            $("#imageValidationError").show();
            deferred.resolve(false);
        }
    };

    image.onerror = function() {
        $("#noFileError").show();
        deferred.resolve(false);
    }

    image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);

    return deferred.promise();
}


$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    var form = this;

    if (isSupportedBrowser()) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Stop the submit for now

        var file = getSelectedFile();
        if (!file) {
            $("#noFileError").show();
            return;
        }

        isGoodImage(file).then(function(isGood) {
            if (isGood)
                form.submit();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the isGoodImage in the readUrl() func:

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            //Add this line, it will check the resoation and display if the image is bad
            isGoodImage(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Its works this way.
Fiddle-https://jsfiddle.net/t2x7zbhs/2/

About the portrait images that are being uploaded, you will need to check the orientation in the "EXIF information" is correct. It can sometimes get broken by different graphic editors.
You can use this "Exif Viewer online" http://regex.info/exif.cgi

Comment: Ah right! I see now! that makes sense! Thank you! One thing I forgot to say also in the message above was that I didn't need the submit button but still wanted it to display a message if the image is good or if its bad instead of being linked to an external webpage if its good but I'm also finding that difficult to wrap my hear around..... any suggestions there? thanks once again!

Comment: Glad to help :)
About the form. Just remove the forms tags and change the submit to a button. Then add click event to that button and add the desierd checks. You can check this fiddle->https://jsfiddle.net/t2x7zbhs/6/. Its the base, from there you can remove the error msg and maybe put success msgs, Just play with it :)

Comment: woo! That also worked! thank you! you've helped a lot! You don't realise how helpful that has actually been!